# Unable to save or update ticket status

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating a ticket booking app for my sample project using Ruby on Rails 4.1. Three are three models - Events, Tickets and Bookings. Events have many tickets and bookings. Tickets have many bookings and they belong to events. Bookings belongs to events and tickets.

Here's the ticket model:

```
class Ticket < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :event
 has_many :bookings

 before_create :check_start_date
 before_update :check_start_date

def self.check_start_date
 if self.booking_start_date == Date.today
    self.update_attribute(:status => 'Open')
end
end
```

The ticket controller:

```
 class TicketsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @tickets = @event.tickets.all
end

def show
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def new
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = Ticket.new
end

def create
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.create(ticket_params)
    if @ticket.save
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'new'
    end
end

def edit
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket= @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])

    if @ticket.update(ticket_params)
        redirect_to [@event, @ticket]
    else
        render 'edit'
    end
end

def destroy
    @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    @ticket = @event.tickets.find(params[:id])
    @ticket.destroy
    redirect_to event_tickets_path
end

private

def ticket_params
    params.require(:ticket).permit(:ticket_name, :booking_start_date, :booking_end_date, :ticket_price, :ticket_quantity, :minimum_quantity, :maximum_quantity, :terms_conditions, :more_information, :status)
end
```

end

The form partial:

```
<%= form_for ([@event, @ticket]) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :ticket_name %>
        <%= f.text_field :ticket_name %>

        <%= f.label :booking_start_date %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :booking_start_date %>

        <%= f.label :booking_end_date %>
        <%= f.datetime_select :booking_end_date %>

        <%= f.label :ticket_price %>
        <%= f.text_field :ticket_price %>

        <%= f.label :ticket_quantity %>
        <%= f.text_field :ticket_quantity %>

        <%= f.label :minimum_quantity %>
        <%= f.text_field :minimum_quantity %>

        <%= f.label :maximum_quantity %>
        <%= f.text_field :maximum_quantity %>

        <%= f.label :terms_contitions %>
        <%= f.text_area :terms_conditions %>

        <%= f.label :more_information %>
        <%= f.text_area :more_information %>
        <%= f.hidden_field :status %>
        <%= f.submit 'Create Ticket' %>
```

I use a hidden field for :status in the form partial and I'm trying to update the value to open or closed based on the model method check_start_date. But, I'm not able to create or update tickets and I get a No Method Error in Tickets Controller, undefined method `check_start_date'.

Where am I going wrong? Is using a hidden field and a model method to update it's status the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Do you need self in the method definition of `check_start_date`. It looks like being used as an instance method than class instance method.
2. Also, do you want to update attribute in `check_start_date` itself to the database or just set it? If you call `update_attribute` inside `check_start_date` could lead to infinite loop.

   `def check_start_date
      if self.booking_start_date == Date.today
        self.status = 'Open'
      end
     end`

Comment: I tried using the method as an instance method. In that case, the ticket creation works fine, but, status column is always empty despite the before filters.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the code, but still the status isn't getting saved.

Answer (score 3):

In your **Ticket** model you have these callbacks:

```
before_create :check_start_date
before_update :check_start_date
```

That means that when you create or update a Ticket object, it will send `:check_start_date` to that object.

You have defined `check_start_date` as a **class method**, but you don't want that. You want that method to be an **instance method**. Why? Well, because that method needs to be sent to instance of the class Ticket, and not to the Ticket itself.

So, change:

```
def self.check_start_date
  if self.booking_start_date == Date.today
    self.update_attribute(:status => 'Open')
  end
end
```

to:

```
def check_start_date  
  if self.booking_start_date == Date.today      
    self.status = 'Open'
  end
end
```

Notice: As [@jvnill](https://stackoverflow.com/users/337166/jvnill) pointed out, you should avoid updating an object that you don't even know if it is persisted in the DB. Let's just set the attribute in the object itself.

Comment: this is correct but you should remember to avoid calling saves and updates on the same object in callbacks.  for example, in this case, if the object is not persisted, you'll get an exception trying to update a non persisted object.

Comment: @nobita the status isn't saved in the DB. The table is empty.

Comment: @Nobita I have updated the code. Still the status isn't saved or updated in the table.

Comment: What is the value of ``self.booking_start_date``? Maybe the problem is that it doesn't even satisfy this condition ``self.booking_start_date == Date.today ``

Comment: @jvnill +1. Edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Nobita self.booking_start_date is a standard datetime field (t.datetime)

Comment: @Nobita Thanks for your answers. I figured it out. DateTime and Date aren't the same. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
def self.check_start_date
  if self.booking_start_date == Date.today
    self.update_attribute(:status => 'Open')
end
```

defines a **class** method. You want an **instance** method. Remove `self.`

```
def check_start_date
  if self.booking_start_date == Date.today
    self.update_attribute(:status => 'Open')
end
```

Comment: I tried using the method as an instance method. In that case, the ticket creation works fine, but, status column is always empty despite the before filters.